# How to close two windows of the same application using python?

Tags: python, automation

I'm working on an automation program in python, I've two windows of cmd open on my screen. I want my code to only close the first window, and leave the second window as it is. How will I make my code determine which window to close?
To close the window I'm using the keyboard package in python, the code writes exit in the cmd window and generates an enter key press to exit the window.

```
keyboard.write("exit") # closes main cmd window
keyboard.press_and_release("enter") # window closes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Windows OS, you can use the pywin32 and win32gui libraries which contain the modules win32gui and win32con which will help search through windows matching a certain name and getting the window handle number (hwnd). Given a hwnd, you can then close the first window that was opened.

You will first need to install pywin32 and wind32gui:

```
pip install win32gui
pip install pywin32
```

Here's the code to close the first command prompt window:

```
import win32gui
import win32con

def windowEnumerationHandler(hwnd, top_windows):
    top_windows.append((hwnd, win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)))

def return_window_hwnd(window_name):
    '''Return list window handles of that match a given window name'''
    windows = []
    win32gui.EnumWindows(windowEnumerationHandler, windows)
    print(windows) #[(67084, 'Command Prompt'), (65868, ''), (722426, 'Command Prompt'), ...]
    hwnds = []
    for wind in windows:
        if window_name in wind[1] or window_name == wind[1]:
            hwnds.append(wind[0])
    return hwnds

# search for Command Prompt windows and return the list of hwnd
command_hwnd_arr = return_window_hwnd('Command Prompt')

# if more than 1 is window open, close the first opened window
if len(command_hwnd_arr) > 1:
    window_handle_to_close = command_hwnd_arr[1]
    win32gui.PostMessage(window_handle_to_close, win32con.WM_CLOSE, 0, 0)
```