# Associate correct windows to define object using pywin32

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32

I want to interact with several applications on Python, knowing that applications are already launch when my script start running. But currently I'm not able to associate a specific window to desire object.

For example, if I open 2 Excel application, they are respectively called Book1 & Book2.
When I launch this python script :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import win32com.client

# First Excel object
exl1 = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
# Second Excel object
exl2 = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
 
# Display names of windows of each object
print(exl1.ActiveWorkbook.FullName)
print(exl2.ActiveWorkbook.FullName)
```

It returns :

```
Book1
Book1
```

So, in fact, the second object isn't associated to the second Excel window.
How can I do to have my python script returning?

```
Book1
Book2
```

From this topic https://stackoverflow.com/a/60139403 I'm able to get the name and associated HWND of each Excel instance, but I didn't find neither how to use it to associate each Excel instance to desire object.